# Decomposing a large text file, with alternating headers and text, into an array of headers and an array of text segments

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I have a very large text file, `test.txt`, in the following format:

```
(Same specific character or word like '^' or '*') Title 1 (end-of-line)

Text 1 (with paragraphs markers, end-of-line markers spaces, all kinds of stuff)

(Same specific character or word like '^' or '*') Title 2 (end-of-line)

Text 2 (with paragraphs markers, spaces, all kinds of stuff)

(Same specific character or word like '^' or '*') Title 3 (end-of-line)

Text 3 (with paragraphs markers, spaces, all kinds of stuff)

...
```

I'd like to make two arrays, one corresponding to the strings `{ "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", ...}`, and the other corresponding to the strings `{ "Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", ...}`.
Is there a simple one-liner to do this?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/r3W9pN2L)'s a specific test example.

Here each line starting with `^` should be a `"Title"` (of which there are three), and the material between the `^` corresponds to `"Text"` (of which there are three sections).  Notice that `^` only appears as the first character in the `"Title"` string, and that each title is finished with an end-of-line, and finally that each `"Text"` section can consist of multiple lines of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `StringSplit`?

```
text = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=r3W9pN2L", "Text"];
StringTrim /@ 
  StringSplit[text, StartOfLine ~~ "^" ~~ Shortest[title__] ~~ EndOfLine :> title]
```

Comment: LOL, this was flagged as "low quality". Is it the case that short posts get flagged auto-magically? I've seen this a few times with short (but quality) answers.

Comment: you might want to put the comment mark back ie `:> "^"<>title`, then you could easily segregate them out with `StringCases`

Comment: The OP wanted only the titles, but I hope he can adapt the example himself to his needs. In the current form it is always `{title, body, title body,...}` so a `Partition[#,2]` and a `Transpose` separates title and bodies easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
input = StringSplit[#, "\n"] & /@ 
  StringSplit[Import["c:\\Users\\Rasher\\Documents\\testtext.txt"], "^"]

title = input[[All, 1]]
text = input[[All, 2 ;;]]
```

Titles in titles, obviously, with indicator stripped.
Text in corresponding text element, as a list with each line of text an element.

Comment: So the "2" in the "[[All, 2 ;;]]" specifies that the title is only one line?

Comment: @CA30- disregard, this is broken, not sure how it slipped by my test. Edit - copied wrong code. Yes, the assumption here is that newline after "^" is end of title.

Comment: @CA30: If you need multi-line titles, you'll need some kind of demarcation obviously, since a newline will not suffice to determine the "end" of a title.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to break up the text section into separate elements for one body of text?  I get: {{"moern#@$@$@#%**((&*)FGDFSDVEEDBDFBDVDFD", "FSDEcc", "SASSKAla", 
  "rejffeioj%%$#$$##!"}, {"fjsiu", "oe"}, {"jncsdhibcvowu", "&&&&&&&",
   "()()()()()()()***)(())"}}

Comment: best do `StringSplit[.., StartOfLine ~~ "^"]` in case the comment token happens to occur elsewhere.